# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject error converting value to type

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a simple webapi hosted at UhuruCloud hosted at http://respro2013webapi.uhurucloud.com/api/values
, which returns a array of strings

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>value1</string>
<string>value2</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

i am using this webapi in my windows phone application, when i use like

```
var books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details[]>(e.Result);
```

it gives exception error converting value "value1" to type

how can i display the results in a list in win phone app

Comment: i have a class named Details
class Details
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
}

thats why i used Details[]

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize XML using a JSON serializer ? It doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1):

Your server appears to be returning XML, and you are trying to parse the XML using a JSON parser, which won't work.  Since you said you are using Web API on the server, I think all you need to do to solve this problem is tell the server you want JSON back, not XML.  (Web API can output either format.)  In your client code, just add an `Accept` header to your request with a value of `application/json`.